# How to display a SQL querie with a shortcode to the WordPress frontend

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I used Wordpress with WooCommerce. Certain orders should not only be visible in the backend, also in the front end.

Now I have created an SQL query (works within phpMyAdmin). The result should be display in a table on the website.

```
SELECT
            p.ID as order_id,
            p.post_date,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'donateAnonym' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as donateAnonym,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
            ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( order_item_name separator '|' ) FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
        FROM
            wp_posts p 
            JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
        GROUP BY
            p.ID
```

I added this code to my theme's functions.php file. Now it is possible to display the information from the function by adding `[showAllHrOrdersTable]` to any page or post.

```
add_shortcode( 'showAllHrOrdersTable', 'showAllHrOrders' );

function showAllHrOrders( $args ) {

    $SQLstring = 'SELECT
            p.ID as order_id,
            p.post_date,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'donateAnonym' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as donateAnonym,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
            ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( order_item_name separator '|' ) FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
        FROM
            wp_posts p 
            JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
        GROUP BY
            p.ID';

    global $wpdb;

    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '</tr><th>Family</th>';
        $content .= '<th>Name</th>';
        $content .= '<th>City</th></tr>';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $SQLstring );

    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content .= '<tr><td>' . $row->_billing_first_name . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>' . $row->_billing_last_name . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>' . $row->_billing_city . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

    return $content;
}
```

**Problem**: When i upload and start the page with the shortcut, the following error appears:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'donateAnonym' (T_STRING) in .../themes/.../functions.php
```

**Notes**:
When i change the SQLString to **SELECT * FROM ...** the error disappears, but some important columns (e.g. donateAnonym) get lost.

```
add_shortcode( 'showAllHrOrdersTable', 'showAllHrOrders' );

function showAllHrOrders( $args ) {

    $SQLstring = 'SELECT *
        FROM
            wp_posts p 
            JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
        GROUP BY
            p.ID';

    global $wpdb;

    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '</tr><th>Family</th>';
        $content .= '<th>Name</th>';
        $content .= '<th>City</th></tr>';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $SQLstring );

    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content .= '<tr><td>' . $row->_billing_first_name . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>' . $row->_billing_last_name . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>' . $row->_billing_city . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

    return $content;
}
```

How can i implement my sql querie without any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape quotes in `$SQLstring`:

```
$SQLstring = 'SELECT
            p.ID as order_id,
            p.post_date,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'donateAnonym\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as donateAnonym,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_billing_email\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_billing_first_name\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_billing_last_name\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_billing_city\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_billing_state\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = \'_order_total\' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
            ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( order_item_name separator \'|\' ) FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
        FROM
            wp_posts p 
            JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
        GROUP BY
            p.ID';
```

Even better and more readable:

```
$SQLstring = "SELECT
            p.ID as order_id,
            p.post_date,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'donateAnonym' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as donateAnonym,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
            max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
            ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( order_item_name separator '|' ) FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
        FROM
            wp_posts p 
            JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
        GROUP BY
            p.ID";
```